# "Side Lobes" When Using a Butterworth filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, python, bandpass, butterworth

So I am attempting to filter a signal containing frequencies at 7Hz, 11Hz, and 74Hz. The signal lasts for 30s and looks like this between -1s and 1s:
[image]

Using a butterworth filter of order 2 with lowcut=8Hz and highcut=4Hz (bandpass) in an attempt to filter the 11Hz component, I get the following overall signal:

[image]

Now, of course, if I amplify this signal by 40 and plot it between -1s and 1s, I get the desired signal:

[image]

My question is what is causing these apparent "side lobes" in the filtered signal (second picture) at the left and right side? Is there a way to get around this? In the end, I want to subtract the filtered signal from the original signal, to remove this frequency. I can't do this, however, with the "side lobes."

These lobes also occur for order 3+ with lowcut=8 and highcut=14

These lobes also occur for lowcut=7 and highcut=15

Comment: To remove a particular frequency, subtraction of a component is hard to get right in practice.  Use a notch filter instead.

Comment: You use a time limited signal and I assume the filter is implemented by a certain tool - the result is not "really" the original signal - the limited 11Hz to 30 seconds result some artifacts.

Comment: Those are not "side lobes".  Those are filter end transients events, due to a finite length or rectangularly windowed signal.

Answer (score 0):

Your signal appears to be the sum of two sinusoidal components of different frequencies; a low-frequency component and a high-frequency component.  In the input, the low-frequency component has a much higher amplitude.

But the bandpass filter reverses the roles of the two frequency components by attenuating the low-frequency component more than it attenuates the high-frequency component.  So the output are the same two frequencies, but here the high-frequency sinusoidal component has a much larger amplitude than the low-frequency sinusoid.